# How can I autowire a list of beans as unmodifiable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I successfully autowired a list of beans like this.

```java
@Autowire
private final List<SpecificType> beans;
```

How can I make it unmodifiable?
More specifically, How can I get autowired with an unmodifiable list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constructor injection and do something like this:

```
@Component
public class ComponentClass {

    private final List<SpecificType> beans;

    public ComponentClass(List<SpecificType> beans) {
        this.beans = Collections.unmodifiableList(beans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this:

```
@Autowire
private final List<SpecificType> beans;
```

Use the class constructor to receive the list and make it immutable.

```
@Component
public YourClass{

   private final List<SpecificType> beans;

   public YourClass(List<SpecificType> beans){

      this.bean = Collections.unmodifiableList(beans);
   }
}
```